# Can laravel Route have no URL?

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing

I have more kind of general question about Laravel.
I am new to it.

I've created a form:

```
{!! Form::model($tourists, ['action' => 'TouristController@store', 'id' => 'passengers_form', 'class' => 'inline' ] ) !!}

{!! Form::close()!!}
```

It outputted: "Action App\Http\Controllers\TouristController@store not defined."

Though *TouristController* and method *store* did existed. 
I tried this and that and then discovered that It works when I add this to my web.php file (routes.php in previous versions):

```
"Route::post('/addtourist', 'TouristController@store');"
```

Ok, I get it, in order to make method work, I should add it to "web.php" (routes).

But what if i have a method which I want to work without 'url'?

For example, I want to send information from form above (or from any other view) to 'TouristController@store' directly, not using '/addtourist'?

smth like

```
 Route::justMakeMethodWorkWithoutAnyURL('TouristController@store');
```

Is that possible?

Sorry if my question is confusing itself. I want to deeper understand Laravel.

Answer (score 1):

It's an old question, but I believe this is what you were looking for:

```php
action('TouristController@store');
```

From the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/urls#urls-for-controller-actions):

> The `action` function generates a URL for the given controller action.

Comment: Thanx, Robert! I am no longer working with Laravel so I forgot the question. I have reread it and I think my question was if you need a URL in order to make some action work. From the anwers above and my experience I can say you need it:)

Comment: @SergejFomin That's true, you always need a URL. Only in this case you don't to specify the actual URL.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this

```
Route::post('/addtourist', 'TouristController@store')->route('tourist');

{!! Form::open(['route' => 'tourist', 'id' => 'passengers_form', 'role' => 'form', 'method' => 'post','class'=>'inline']) !!}
```

Hope this work for you !

Comment: thank you) but wanted to know if URL is a required parameter when declaring a route?
because i think there can be situations where you want to use a method with any URL. (for example the method about is used only to add a new user to the database). 
I've 'reserved' '/addtourist' for this method, but there can be a situation i would use this url for some other purpose and forget that it is reserved already. 
Sorry if it sounds like nonsense:)

Comment: You can use same URL with different method. For example, `Route::post('/addtourist', 'abcController@abc')` and `Route::get('/addtourist', 'abcController@bcd')`. But once this is used with both methods, then you can't use again `Route::post('/addtourist', 'xyzController@abc')` Or `Route::get('/addtourist', 'xyzController@abc')` In your case, you can use `Route::post('/addtourist', 'TouristController@store')`. Now you can't use again `Route::post('/addtourist', 'TravelsController@store')`. Hope you understand!! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is simply to write a class and then include it in your php file to call it's methods.

Routes are used, by definition, to map urls to some logic handler. In your example of a form, you would necessarily have to post the data to a url because that's what html forms do.